# Spring security filter by authenticated user

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

What is in Spring Boot the best way to filter all queries of entity adding the authenticated user check (using the Authentication Name field)?

1. Adding a where hibernate on the entity? Is it possible?
2. Adding Spring Security postFilter? I didn't understand if I should add it to my repository or to my service. Isn't it an inefficient system (than executing a filtered query)?

**EDIT**
No, I'm not using Spring-Data, but I can add it to my project.

For example, if my repository is:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long>, QuerydslPredicateExecutor<MyEntity>, QuerydslBinderCustomizer<QMyEntity> {
  ...
}
```

I have to override all methods of the classes of JpaRepository and QuerydslPredicateExecutor and QuerydslPredicateExecutor that I use in my project? It's correct?

Comment: No you don't need to override anything when you use the Spring-Data repositories. The concrete implementations are magically auto-generated for you from the JpaRepository/CrudRepository/etc stubs. The Spring docs are particularly good; you should read them over re Spring Data repositories.

Comment: Thanks to @Thomas I was able to filter many of my queries, but I can't find any documentation explaining how to integrate Spring Security and QueryDSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The postFilter is not an efficient option since it would result in fetching many data from the database, but throwing most of them away.

If you're using Spring Data JPA, then you can use the [Spring Security data integration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#data) and do something like this to include the authentication name in the query (automatically fetched from the SecurityContext).

```
@Repository
public interface BillingRepository extends JpaRepository<Billing,Long> {
    @Query("select b from Billing b where b.userId = ?#{ authentication?.name }")
    Ierable<Billing> findBillings();
}
```